# Casefold() wont work on python 3.7.0 mac AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'casefold'

Tags: python, macos, python-3.7, attributeerror

I have tried without adding `str()` before the casefold call but it gives me the same AttributeError:

> Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'casefold' error.

After looking online I found the other post that said casefold is part of python 3.3 and above but I am on python 3.7.3.

```
def str_manipulation(string):
   print("Your word was:"+ str(string)+"now it is:"+ (str(string)).casefold())

if __name__ == "__main__":
   word = "hello"
   str_manipulation(word)
```

Comment: are you sure you are running `python 3.7.3`? What is the output if you run `python --version`?

Comment: Its working fine with python3 .

Comment: @beer44, it also works with Python 3.7.4.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf  , yes its supported on all later version even in (dev 3.9 ) https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold